# How to add timezone to time and date in LibreOffice for inclusion in an auto-updated field in a footer?

Tags: document, libreoffice, issue-tracking, timestamp-with-timezone, libreoffice-writer

[LibreOffice Writer Format Number Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n6Yb.png)

I would like to be very specific about the last print and edit of a copy of a document.  I may go to a different timezone soon. Other people with different versions of the document are elsewhere.

Are there better ways to do this?
Should I file a request on their issue tracker?

Comment: Is this question about programming\scripting? Or you want to do this from UI in LibreOffice?

Comment: I would prefer to do it from the UI.